# How to define a validation regular expression pattern for a prisma model attribute type?

Tags: prisma

In prisma schema, I want to define a simple model like:

```
model NaturalPerson {
    id  String @@id   
    cpf String?
}
```

but here is the catch:  I want the attribute `cpf` to match a certain regular expression `^[0-9]{11}$`.

Is it possible to define such validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define this validation in the schema file, you can enforce it while creating records.

Before invoking the prisma create query you could use [Joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi) to validate the value which is being inserted.

Here's how you can match your regex pattern: [Joi pattern regex](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.6.0#objectpatternpattern-schema-options)